# $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log(x+1)}{x}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How can I prove it without using Taylor series, L'Hopital's rule, or integrals,or series expansion? I don't know how. Please help.

First I have tried to use epsilon-delta, I also tried to use sequences but I failed.

Comment: Are you allowed to use L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: No. @KaboMurphy

Comment: What is your definition of the logarithm?

Comment: Also don't know$ athop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  \pm \infty } \left( {1 + \frac{1}
{x}} \right)^x  = e$

Comment: @MartinR the inverse function of exp. Exp x is the series

Comment: Then how do you want to prove it *without* using Taylor series? Note that the definition of $\exp$ as a Taylor series easily implies $\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{e^y-1}{y} = 0$, and that implies your desired limit.

Comment: Suppose I knew $\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{e^y-1}{y} = 1$ It is 1, it is written in the book. I have recognized the limit it is on p.131 of Walter analysis. But it is really 1. So suppose I knew this limit how to continue?

Comment: I suggest that you clarify your question with the necessary information (such as how log/exp are defined). Requiring “without using Taylor series” does not make much sense if the definitions are based on Taylor series. – Also note that [your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969).

Answer (score 1):

The [Inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Inequalities) section of Wikipedia's "List of Logarithmic Identities" page states

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x+x^2/12}} \le \ln(1 + x) \le \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x}} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

for $0 \le x$, and the reverse for $-1 \lt x \le 0$. Dividing by $x$ and then having $x \to 0^{+}$ as shown, and with the reverse inequalities for $x \to 0^{-}$, gives $1$ on either side in both cases. Thus, by the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), you have

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x} = 1 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Comment: Does not help me

Comment: @New2Math This answers your question as you've written it. Since it doesn't help you, I suggest you reword your question to be more explicit about what you are willing to, and not willing to, accept for an answer. Thanks.

Comment: It is too difficult

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** For $x >0$ whenever when $n \leq \frac{1}{x} <n+1$ you have
$$\log (1+\frac{1}{n+1})^n\leq \frac{\log(x+1)}{x} \leq \log (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$$

Use the fact that

$$\lim_n (1+\frac{1}{n+1})^n= \lim_n (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}=e$$

**Edit** With your definition of $e$.

**Hint 1:** Use your definition of $e$ to show that 
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x} =e$$

**Hint 2** If you meet it, apply the formula for $(f^{-1})'(0)$. If not, calculate 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log(x+1)}{x}$$
via the substitution $x=e^y-1$. Then, you get 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log(x+1)}{x}=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log(e^y-1+1)}{e^y-1}$$

Comment: The last fact is not written in the book. We have defined e as exp(1) where exp(x)= $\sum x^n/n!$ we also know that exp(x)= $\sum^n x^n/n!+ R_{n+1}$ with $|R_{n+1}|\leq 2|x^{n+1}/(n+1!)|$ with $x\leq 1+0.5n$ now help me please. I had to write down everything on mobile phone because my computer is broken

Comment: @New2Math The usual definition of $e$ is the one in my post. I will correct the answer to use your definition.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  \pm \infty } \left( {1 + \frac{1}
{x}} \right)^x  = e
$$
you have that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  \pm \infty } x\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}
{x}} \right) = 1
$$
Now, let be $t=\frac{1}{x}$. You have that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{1}
{t}\log \left( {1 + t} \right) = 1
$$

Comment: We have not talked about this identity of e

Answer (score 0):

Still calculus approach, just no integrals or explicit L'Hopital:

Let $\varphi(x)=\log(x+1)-x$ for $x>0$, then $\varphi'(x)<0$ for $x>0$, so $\varphi(x)\leq\varphi(0)=0$, we get $\dfrac{\log(1+x)}{x}\leq 1$ for $x>0$.

On the other hand, let $\varphi(x)=\log(x+1)-x+x^{2}/2$ for $0<x<1$, then $\varphi'(x)>0$ for $0<x<1$, so $\dfrac{\log(x+1)}{x}\geq 1-\dfrac{1}{2}x$ for $0<x<1$.

Finally, one concludes by Squeeze Theorem.

For negative part, we exploit the trick like the following:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}\dfrac{\log(x+1)}{x}&=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{\log(1-y)}{-y}\\
&=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{-\log(1-y)}{y}\\
&=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{1}{1-y}\right)}{y}\\
&=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{\log\left(1+\dfrac{y}{1-y}\right)}{y}\\
&=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{\log\left(1+\dfrac{y}{1-y}\right)}{\dfrac{y}{1-y}}\dfrac{1}{1-y}\\
&=1\cdot 1\\
&=1.
\end{align*}

Comment: What is $\varphi'$ I also don't know that $e= \lim (n+1/n)^n$

Comment: I didn't use the limit fact. And $\varphi'$ is the derivative of $\varphi$, I use the derivative criterion to show the monotonicity of the function $\varphi$.

Comment: But we haven't talked about derivatives yet

Comment: Then I really don't know how to help, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have stated you know that exp(x) = $\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Let $\log(1+x) = a \implies e^a-1=x$

as $ x \to 0 \ , a\to0 $

Now, the question rephrases to $\lim_{a \to 0}\frac{a}{e^a-1} $ , Now using the expansion of exp(a) the limit evaluates to 1.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you appear to accept that
$$\lim_{y\to0}\frac{e^y-1}y=1.$$
As $x\to0$, $1+x\to1$ and so $\ln(1+x)\to0$. Therefore
setting $y=\ln(1+x)$ gives
$$1=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{e^y-1}y=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1+x)-1}{\ln(1+x)}
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\ln(1+x)}$$
etc.